# Docker is not copying file on a shared volume during build

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I would like to have the files created on the building phase stored on my local machine

I have this Dockerfile

```
FROM node:17-alpine as builder
WORKDIR '/app' 

COPY ./package.json ./   
RUN npm install
RUN npm i -g @angular/cli

COPY . .
RUN ng build foo --prod  
RUN touch test.txt #This is just for test

CMD ["ng", "serve"] #Just for let the container running
```

I also created a shared volume via docker compose

```
services:  
  client:
      build:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
        context: ./foo
      volumes:
        - /app/node_modules 
        - ./foo:/app
```

If I attach a shell to the running container and run `touch test.txt`, the file is created on my local machine.
I can't understand why the files are not created on the building phase...

If I use a multi stage Dockerfile the dist folder on the container is created (just adding this to the Dockerfile), but still I can't see it on the local machine

```
FROM nginx
EXPOSE 80 
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/foo /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I can't understand why the files are not created on the building
> phase...

That's because the build phase doesn't involve volume mounting.

Mounting volumes only occur when creating containers, not building images. If you map a volume to an existing file or directory, Docker "overrides" the image's path, much like a traditional linux mount. Which means, before creating the container, you *image* has everything from `/app/*` pre-packaged, and that's why you're able to copy the contents in the multistage build.

However, as you defined a volume with the  `- ./foo:/app` config in your docker-compose file, the *container* won't have those files anymore, and instead the `/app` folder will have the current contents of your `./foo` directory.

If you wish to copy the contents of the image to a mounted volume, you'll have to do it in the ENTRYPOINT, as it runs upon container instantiation, and after the volume mounting.

Comment: Thanks for the exaustive answer, could you provide a small example ... that would be super appreciated